# Are these inversion? "Shall I say" & "shall my eyes gleam"

Tags: word-meaning, paraphrasing

> **Shall my eyes gleam** under the moon of your glance,
>
> as though it has never ever been a day entering the night,
>
> **shall I say** your eyes resemble the sun.

I would also be really grateful if you would paraphrase the poem into simple English.
Does the word "shall" refer to a must?

Comment: Yes, they're inversions: they're questions. *Shall* in this context asks the person addressed if the course of action suggested is desired and permitted. 'Paraphrasing' the poem is by definition impossible; and in any case it would be Literary Criticism, which is off-topic here.

Comment: I'd say that in this instance "shall" means "should".

Answer (score 1):

We can take the poem phrase by phrase and see how the language works at the linguistic level, but not at the poetic level, which is off-topic here.

> the moon of your glance

is roughly equivalent to "the moon that is your glance" -- in other words, your glance is in some respect(s) a moon.  This is not the usual "of" where it would mean "the moon that *belongs to* your glance".

*Shall* is not an imperative, as in "You shall not covet your neighbor's Porsche."  "Shall" + bare infinitive of the verb (here: shall gleam, shall say)  is a future tense form, and thus refers to *actions contemplated*.